# Linux batch command to get users that start from a specific string

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to get the users that start with a "ab" or end with "1" . Only users. The following command works with who, but for some reason not with users.

```
users | grep -e "^ab" -e "1$"
```

and the result is I get all users of the system

Comment: If there's more than one user, the `users` command lists them on one line (well, at least it lists multiple users per line; I've not experimented with lots and lots and lots of logins), whereas `who` lists users one per line. I'm doubtful that your regex is sensitive enough to handle this properly (with `who`, the `1$` would be matching a time field, unless you've included filtering you've not shown).

Comment: Why not use  `awk` on `/etc/passwd` ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch That's an option if you're looking among *all* users, regardless of whether they're logged in or not. Even though the OP's wording doesn't state it explicitly, his/her choice of `users` (and `who`) implies that it's about _logged-in_ users. @blended: Correct?

Comment: @mklement0 yes,correct ,this is for a uny assignment and we are not allowed to use awk among others

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`users` outputs the logged-in users on a *single* line. If you want to match them with `grep` separately, split the output from `users` into individual lines first, by replacing each space with a newline:

```
 users | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -e "^ab" -e "1$"
```

---

**Update**: Alternatively, you can skip the `tr` step if you use grep's `-o` option (to output all matching *substrings* rather than only lines) and use `\b` to match on *word* boundaries (replace `*` with `+` if "ab" and "1" by themselves shouldn't match):

```
users | grep -o -e '\bab\w*' -e '\b\w*1'
```

(**OSX** users: inexplicably, the above sometimes skips matches - observed on 10.9 with input string `"ab 1 abc x1"`; you can work around this by combining the regexes into a single one and using `egrep` or `grep -E`:

```
users | egrep -o '\b(ab\w*|\w*1)'
```

)

Answer (score 1):

The output of `users` is run together, on one line.

The output of `who` is split, one per a line, with additional details following.

Your use of `^` and `$` will only match the start or end of a line.

```
  who | grep -e '^ab' -e '1$'
```

… says to match users whose names begin with "ab" or whose *terminal from which they are logged in* (or some other field, depending on your `who` version, possibly time) ends with a `1`, since the login terminal is the last field in `who`.

To match just user names from `who`, you can `cut` the output into fields on spaces, and take the first field:

```
   who | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | grep -e '^ab' -e '1$'
```

To match the output of `users`, you can't use the start and end of line markers `^…$`, but you can test for "word boundaries" with `\b`

```
   users | grep -e '\bab' -e '1\b'
```

If you're trying to extract matching names in a sequence:

```
   users | grep -o -e '\bab\w*\b' -e '\b\w*1\b'
```

If you need to extract the list of users (splitting on spaces) and test each one, e.g. to perform some action, you can use `read`:

```
    users | while read -d ' ' user
    do
        if echo $user | grep -q -e '^ab' -e '1$'
        then
            echo "you have a nice name" | write $user
        fi
    done
```

As @mklement points out in comments, BASH has its own builtin regex match as well:

```
   users | while read -d ' ' user
   do
       if [[ $user =~ '^ab|1$' ]]
       then
            echo "this is a little nicer way to match, $user" | write $user
       fi
   done
```

Comment: +1 for this comprehensive answer, but your `grep` solution with `\b` needs some love: `-o` is missing to only output matching substrings and the `-e` regexes must be modified to match a single token only; quibble: not all versions of `who` list the terminal last (on OSX 10.9 and Ubuntu 12.04 the time comes last, for instance).

Comment: Hadn't thought of that being a goal (`-o`) but added that in. And odd that Ubuntu differs from Fedora; I'm not at all surprised that Darwin does things differently, totally different ancestry there. (OP did specify Linux though.) Augmented with your suggestions

Comment: Thanks for updating; to make the `-o` variant output the actual usernames and not just the matching prefix/suffix, you need `-e '\bab\w*' -e '\b\w*1'`.

Comment: Re your loop solution: you must add `-d ' '` to `read` to make this work - otherwise, all usernames will be read at once. You could simplify your `if` statement to `if echo $user | grep -q -e '^ab' -e '1$'`, or even to `if [[ $user =~ ^ab|1$ ]]`.